# Pure virtual functions with templated inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am attempting to implement polymorphism with a templated derived class. See below:

```
//templated base class
template <class num> class A{
protected:
    num x;
    num y;

public:
    A( num x0 = 0, num y0 = 0) {
       x = x0;
       y = y0;
    }
    virtual void print_self() = 0;

};

//derived class
template < class num > class B: public A < num > {
   public:
      B( num x1 = 0, num y1 = 0):shape < num > ( x1 , y1 ) { }
      void print_self(){
          std::cout << "x is " << x << " and y is " << y << endl;
      }
};
```

The base class has pure virtual function print_self(). When trying to define the function in the derived class, I received the following error:

```
'x' was not declared in this scope
```

The same for y.
So somehow the derived class doesn't have access to the variables x and y even though it is listed as protected.

Is there some other way to define print_self(), or is this simply not possible? If it is not possible, can you suggest another approach?

Comment: Use `this->x` and `this->y`.

Comment: The use of `this` is redundant here.

Comment: You can also use `A<num>::x` and `A<num>::y` or `typedef A<num> base` and then `base::x`, etc.

Comment: Your code is correct. Where did you get the error?

Comment: @Raindrop7 Nope, `this` is in fact needed here. Using Visual C++ by any chance? I think they allow it, but it's not standard.

Comment: @DeiDei: Yes I am using `MSVC` and it doesn't complain. So is it really a must to use `this` in this case? What is the OP using (compiler)?

Comment: @Raindrop7 Yes, either use `this->` or the possibilities I mentioned above, or the answer below. Either way, the names inside a base class are not implicitly visible in a derived class.

Comment: @DeiDei: Thank you! Get it.

Comment: @Raindrop7 no, it isn't redundant, it's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using templated inheritance, the existence of `x` and `y` are dependent of the template argument. In other words the base class part of `this` pointer become a dependent name. You must use the `this` pointer explicitly or use using.

```
template<typename num>
struct B : A<num> {
    using A<num>::x;
    using A<num>::y;

    void print_self(){
        std::cout << "x is " << x << " and y is " << y << endl;
    }
};
```

Or even:

```
template<typename num>
struct B : A<num> {
    void print_self() {
        std::cout << "x is " << this->x << " and y is " << this->y << endl;
    }
};
```